# Github Actions/variable-mapper : Error: Unexpected token *** in JSON

Tags: json, yaml, github-actions

Using variable-mapper in my workflow, I'm trying to map secrets and host depending on a workflow input named environment.
Partial yaml file is as follows :

```
  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      environment:
        required: true
        default: 'test'
        type: choice
        description: Which environment ?
        options:
          - test
          - staging
          - prod
      
      build_assets:
        required: false
        type: boolean
        description: Build assets ?

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
    
    - name: Project Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Node version Setup
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '18.17.1'
        cache: 'npm'

    - name: Map environment variables
      uses: kanga333/variable-mapper@master
      with:
        key: "${{inputs.environment}}"
        map: |
          {
            "prod": {
              "environment": "production",
              "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"
            },
            "staging": {
              "environment": "staging",
              "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_STAGING }}"
            },
            ".*": {
              "environment": "test",
              "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_TEST }}"
            }
          }

    - name: Echo environment
      run: echo ${{ env.environment }}
```

My worflow fails with following error:

```
  with:
    key: test
    map: {
    "prod": {
      "environment": "production",
      "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "***"
    },
    "staging": {
      "environment": "staging",
      "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "***"
    },
    ".*": {
      "environment": "test",
      "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "***"
    }
  }
  
    export_to: log,env
    mode: first_match
Error: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 108
```

I've already checked that my map JSON is correct, I don't get what I'm missing here.
Looks like there is a special character somewhere, by it don't see any.
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/kanga333/variable-mapper/issues/105

Comment: Are those SSH private keys single or multiline secrets? BTW, you could use [`type: environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputsinput_idtype) instead of `type: choice`. Also, this switch seems like a hack when you can configure per environment secrets and switch via [`environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment) config.